# Django ForeignKey from multiple objects

Tags: python, django

I'm creating an app where a user can subscribe/follow to different aspects of the site.

I'm building the table which will record all these subscriptions. My initial instinct is to make one Subscription Table, which will list everything that is subscribed to. Here is how I'm planning it now:

```
class SubscriptionTypeCode(object):
    CITY = '1'
    REGION = '2'
    COUNTRY = '3'
    USER = '4'

SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    (SubscriptionTypeCode.CITY, 'City'),
    (SubscriptionTypeCode.REGION, 'Region'),
    (SubscriptionTypeCode.COUNTRY, 'Country'),
    (SubscriptionTypeCode.USER, 'User'),
)
class Subscription(models.Model):
    subscriber = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="subscriber")
    subscription_type = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE_CHOICES)
    subscription_to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="subscription_to_user", null=True, blank=True)
    subscription_to_city = models.ForeignKey(City, null=True, blank=True)
    subscription_to_country = models.ForeignKey(Country, null=True, blank=True)
    subscription_to_region = models.ForeignKey(Region, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
    cancelled = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

This should work, but i'm wondering if it's the most efficient way to do this. Each row will have the subscriber ID, then the type choice, and then depending on that, one of the subscription_to columns will have a foreign object.

This is working, but is requiring a lot of if/else statements in the logic. For example

```
def create_subscription(request, subscription_type, subscription_id):
    subscription = Subscription.create(
        subscriber = request.user,
        subscription_type = subscription_type,
    )
    if subscription_type == SubscriptionTypeCode.REGION:
        region = get_region(subscription_id)
        subscription.subscription_to_region = region

    elif subscription_type == SubscriptionTypeCode.CITY:
        city = get_city(subscription_id)
        subscription.subscription_to_city = city

    elif subscription_type == SubscriptionTypeCode.COUNTRY:
        country = get_country(subscription_id)
        subscription.subscription_to_country = country

    elif subscription_type == SubscriptionTypeCode.USER:
        user = get_user(subscription_id)
        subscription.subscription_to_user = user

    subscription.save()
    return subscription
```

Any thoughts on how to simplify this?  Or is this okay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [generic foreign keys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) (with a single `subscription_to` field) or [model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance) (having subclasses of `Subscription` for the different subscription types, which would at least allow you to structure your code better).